# NPM Install: Command timed out after 900 seconds on CodeDeploy

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, npm-install

Not exactly sure what is taking so long for npm to install on my EC2 instance, but here's the log output:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
2020/10/10 00:43:19.430098 [INFO] Downloading: bucket: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-665496786822,object: /resources/environments/e-779g33dt9k/_runtime/versions/manifest_1602290543372
2020/10/10 00:43:19.636192 [INFO] Download successful243bytes downloaded
2020/10/10 00:43:19.636422 [INFO] Trying to read and parse version manifest...
2020/10/10 00:43:19.636595 [INFO] Executing instruction: stopSqsd
2020/10/10 00:43:19.636602 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip stop sqsd daemon...
2020/10/10 00:43:19.636606 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2020/10/10 00:44:03.357499 [INFO] extracting 
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundleto/var/app/staging/
2020/10/10 00:44:03.357569 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o 
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2020/10/10 00:44:03.972792 [INFO] finished extracting 
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2020/10/10 00:44:03.973892 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunConfigDeployPreBuildHooks
2020/10/10 00:44:03.973905 [WARN] skipping hooks scripts under /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/
2020/10/10 00:44:03.973917 [INFO] The dir .platform/confighooks/prebuild/ does not exist in the 
application. Skipping this step...
2020/10/10 00:44:03.973922 [INFO] Executing instruction: Install customer specified node.js version
2020/10/10 00:44:03.973927 [INFO] installing specified nodejs version...
2020/10/10 00:44:03.974861 [INFO] validate the node.js version specified by customer...
2020/10/10 00:44:03.974877 [INFO] Nodejs 12.16.1 has already been installed, skipping
2020/10/10 00:44:03.974882 [INFO] Executing instruction: Use NPM to install dependencies
2020/10/10 00:44:03.974895 [INFO] use npm to install dependencies
2020/10/10 00:44:03.974932 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c npm config set jobs 1
2020/10/10 00:44:10.557446 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c npm --production install
2020/10/10 00:59:11.436998 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [config-deploy] - 
[Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm -- 
production install failed with error Command timed out after 900 seconds
```

I'm using the full CodePipeline, here is my `buildspec.yml` (spacing abbreviated):

```
# Buildspec version
version: 0.2
frontend:
 phases:
  preBuild:
   commands:
     - echo Installing NPM dependencies...
     - npm ci
  build:
   commands:
     - npm run-script build
 artifacts:
  baseDirectory: build
  files:
   - '**/*'
 cache:
  paths:
```

This should output a directory `build` for CodeDeploy, which uses this `appspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/app/current
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Beanstalk likes to try to do things its own way, and I have it set to the Nodejs platform so it is going to try to run npm install and npm start at all costs.

I ended up disabling it through not including my package.json or package lock files in CodeBuild's artifact. This at least stopped it from trying to run its own NPM install. Not exactly efficient and I port all my node_modules over but it is zipped as an artifact from CodeBuild and sent to Beanstalk for deployment.